# Laravel Explode Ajax Request Containing Name and Numbers

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using `laravel 8.4` .

My route :

```
Route::post('test',[\App\Http\Controllers\DataController::class, 'store'])->name('pos-test');
```

My Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 //   DB::table('data')->insert('product_code',$request->id);
    $badge = explode(' ', $request);
    $employee_id = $badge[0];

    \DB::table('data')->insert(['product_code'=> $employee_id]);       

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Product saved successfully.']);

}
```

Ajax code :

```
function handleBarcode(scanned_barcode) {
    //handle your code here....
    console.log(scanned_barcode);

            let _token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      event.preventDefault();
     $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
     });
  $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('pos-test') }}",
        type: "POST",            // Can change this to get if required
        data: {
          code : scanned_barcode,
          _token: _token
        },
        success: function(data) {
                 $("#status").html(data);      
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               $("#status").text(textStatus);
               console.log(jqXHR);
        }
  });

};
```

The request is like this "`555444 Razif Raziq`" , i would like to explode it so I may insert only "`555444`" into table but in table column `product_code` is '`POST`' .

[image: It should contain 555444 instead of POST word]

The question is how to fix it? thank you

Comment: add ajax code and mention what you have error in

Comment: i just add an ajax code and picture .

Comment: what is the  console.log(scanned_barcode); output ?

Answer (score 1):

you must explode your correct data in request object not request object itself.

```
$badge = explode(' ', $request->code);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 'code' value is sent correctly, just use this

> $request->code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
\DB::table('data')->insert(['product_code'=> $request->code]);       

return response()->json(['success'=>'Product saved successfully.']);
```

}